# How to format ng-model string to date for angular material datepicker

Tags: angularjs, date, mongoose, angular-material

I have a **mongoose** connection to a database containing Date objects in a collection. I want to view these Date objects using Angular Material's `DatePicker` control. The Date object follow the **ISO string format**.

Here is a code snippet:

```
<md-datepicker 
     ng-model="license.expirationdate" md-placeholder="Enter date">
</md-datepicker>
```

I get the following error:

The `ng-model` for `md-datepicker` must be a Date instance.

When researching, I found that you can use filters to create a Date instance but this did not work for me -> I got an error message saying that the model value is non-assignable when using a simple filters. The filter simply returned a new Date object based on the string input.

How can I format the strings to Date objects while still allowing for `ng-model` changes?

EDIT: schema for mongoose
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var modelschema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    licensetype : String,
    activationcount : Number,
    expirationdate: Date,
    key : String
})
```

here is the express routing which populates the schema

```
app.post('/licenses', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.expirationDate);
    License.create({

        name: req.body.licenseName,
        licensetype: req.body.licenseType,
        activationcount: 0,
        expirationdate: req.body.expirationDate,
        key: "123456"
    }, function (err, license) {

        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            console.log(err);
        }

        //Send user back to main page
        res.writeHead(301, {
            'Location': '/',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end();
    }
    )

});
```

Comment: What does `license.expirationdate` look like?

Comment: It is set using the same DatePicker control and gives the following result: 2015-12-15T23:00:00.000Z

Comment: Ok can you show the code where you are populating `license.expirationdate` or even just `licsense` please? In what way you do you want the model to change - like is new date going to come in and you want it to re-populate the datepicker? do you want to change the date and send it back out  or what?

Comment: expirationdate is populated by simply sending the DatePicker's output to mongoose schema with the expirationdate type being Date. I want the DatePicker to properly view the Date stored in the database and I would like to use the ng-changed event to update the database when I change the date on the DatePicker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an example:

Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <md-datepicker ng-model="dt" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-change="license.expirationdate = dt.toISOString()">
    </md-datepicker>
    {{license.expirationdate}}
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.license = {
        expirationdate: '2015-12-15T23:00:00.000Z'
    };

    $scope.dt = new Date($scope.license.expirationdate);

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/jm6y12un/

UPDATE:

With `ng-repeat`:

Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="d in data">
        <md-datepicker
            ng-model="dataMod[$index].dt"
            md-placeholder="Enter date"
            ng-change="d.license.expirationdate = dataMod[$index].dt.toISOString()">
        </md-datepicker>
        {{d.license.expirationdate}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    var i;

    $scope.data = [ 
        { license:
            { expirationdate: '2015-12-15T23:00:00.000Z' }
        },
        { license:
            { expirationdate: '2015-12-20T23:00:00.000Z' }
        },
        { license:
            { expirationdate: '2015-12-25T23:00:00.000Z' }
        }
    ];

    $scope.dataMod = [];
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i += 1) {
        $scope.dataMod.push({
            dt: new Date($scope.data[i].license.expirationdate)
        });
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/bmqpyu8g/

Comment: thanks for your example. This clarifies a lot. How would I create the date instances if I populate a table using ng-repeat and a collection?

Answer (score 10):

You can use ng-init, a custom filter, and ng-change and accomplish this in markup.

JavaScript:

```
app.filter('toDate', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return new Date(input);
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<md-datepicker
     ng-init="date = (license.expirationdate | toDate)"
     ng-model="date"
     ng-change="license.expirationdate = date.toISOString()"
     md-placeholder="Enter date">
</md-datepicker>
```

With this approach, you don't need to clutter your Controller code with View logic.  The drawback is that any programmatic changes to license.expirationdate in the Controller will not be reflected in the View automatically.

Comment: Thanks so much, we were trying to avoid messing with the controller code. <3

Answer (score 8):

http://jsfiddle.net/katfby9L/1/

```
// Configure the $httpProvider by adding our date transformer
app.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.push(function(responseData){
        convertDateStringsToDates(responseData);
        return responseData;
    });
}]);

var regexIso8601 = /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/;

function convertDateStringsToDates(input) {
    // Ignore things that aren't objects.
    if (typeof input !== "object") return input;

    for (var key in input) {
        if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        var value = input[key];
        var match;
        // Check for string properties which look like dates.
        // TODO: Improve this regex to better match ISO 8601 date strings.
        if (typeof value === "string" && (match = value.match(regexIso8601))) {
            // Assume that Date.parse can parse ISO 8601 strings, or has been shimmed in older browsers to do so.
            var milliseconds = Date.parse(match[0]);
            if (!isNaN(milliseconds)) {
                input[key] = new Date(milliseconds);
            }
        } else if (typeof value === "object") {
            // Recurse into object
            convertDateStringsToDates(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This will automatically convert all strings in server JSON responses to date

Comment: This is brilliant.  Saves a lot of the headache of looping through the response data.

Answer (score 6):

I would do it like this:

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="d in data">
        <md-datepicker
            ng-init="date = StrToDate(d.license.expirationdate);"
            ng-model="date"
            md-placeholder="Enter date"
            ng-change="d.license.expirationdate = date.toISOString()">
        </md-datepicker>
        {{d.license.expirationdate}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.StrToDate = function (str) {
            return new Date(str);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to make a default date of 6 months from the current day back...

After quite lengthy experiments with date conversion to ISO format and back, I created a simple solution that I did not find here.

The general idea: Take time today and add / subtract time in milliseconds until the required date.

html:

```
<div flex-gt-xs>
   <h4 class="md-title">Date From:</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.sixMonthBeforeNow" md-placeholder="Date From:"></md-datepicker>
      {{vm.sixMonthBeforeNow}}
</div>
```

controller:

```
vm.sixMonthBeforeNow = new Date((+new Date) - 15778800000); // today - 6 month in ISO format (native for Angular Material Datepicker)
```

result:
[image]

Maybe it will be useful for someone...

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom directive to handle this for me. I have used the Date class from [Sugarjs.com](http://sugarjs.com) in order for it to work as I have implemented it. This method ensures the date always gets displayed like a date and doesn't jump around with UTC offset involved. You can change the formatter to `return new Date(input)` if you don't want to confine to UTC.

```
angular.module 'app.components'
 .directive 'autoChangeStringDates', ->
   directive =
     restrict: 'A'
     require: 'ngModel'
     priority: 2000
     link: (scope, el, attrs, ngModelController) ->
       ngModelController.$formatters.push((input) ->
         if typeof input == Date
          return input
         else
           return Date.create(input, {fromUTC: true})
       )
    return
```

You then use it in your HTML markup like so

```
<md-datepicker ng-model='myModel' auto-change-string-dates></md-datepicker>
```